# Why can Python coroutines not be called recursively?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, coroutine

I have been using Python coroutines instead of threading with some success. It occurred to me that I might have a use for a coroutine that knows about itself, so it can send itself something. I found that this is not possible (in Python 3.3.3 anyway). To test, I wrote the following code:

```
def recursive_coroutine():
    rc = (yield)
    rc.send(rc)

reco = recursive_coroutine()
next(reco)
reco.send(reco)
```

This raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rc.py", line 7, in <module>
    reco.send(reco)
  File "rc.py", line 3, in recursive_coroutine
    rc.send(rc)
ValueError: generator already executing
```

Although the error is clear, it feels like this should be possible. I never got as far as to come up with a useful, realistic application of a recursive coroutine, so I'm not looking for an answer to a specific problem. Is there a reason, other than perhaps implementation difficulty, that this is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible because for `send` to work, the coroutine has to be waiting for input. `yield` pauses a coroutine, and `send` and `next` unpause it. If the generator is calling `send`, it can't simultaneously be paused and waiting for input.

If you could `send` to an unpaused coroutine, the semantics would get really weird. Suppose that `rc.send(rc)` line worked. Then `send` would continue the execution of the coroutine from where it left off, which is the send call... but there is no value for `send` to return, because we didn't hit a yield.

Suppose we return some dummy value and continue. Then the coroutine would execute until the next `yield`. At that point, what happens? Does execution rewind so `send` can return the yielded value? Does the `yield` discard the value? Where does control flow go? There's no good answer.

Comment: I would expect a `send` to just start executing at the next available `yield` in the coroutine (which isn't present in the example, but ... )

Comment: @gens: How do you know what the next available `yield` is? What if it's in a loop, or a conditional, or a `with` block? Jumping to the next yield, whatever "next" may mean, isn't particularly useful behavior.

Comment: I see your point and why 'the next `yield`' is not clear. However I'm not convinced there are no better answers than to raise an exception. What if `send` would just put the sent value on an input queue and the routine would remain running (like it already was). When it hits a subsequent `yield` it would pop the latest value off the input queue and return it. If the queue is empty, it would pause like it does today.

Comment: @gens: Then `send` has to return twice, once so the coroutine can carry on to the next `yield` and once when it hits `yield`. You also run into problems where the queue never empties, because if the `send`s get ahead of the `yield`s, nothing allows the `yield`s to catch up.

Comment: If you try really hard, make a lot of arbitrary decisions, and handle a lot of edge cases, you can get some sort of definite behavior out of the whole mess. It's too much extra complexity for no real use case, though.

Comment: Right, understood. Unless someone can come up with a  sensible way for the control flow to work, disallowing it is perhaps not so bad. Thanks for thinking it through.